# Subdomain for Laravel Rest API not working correctly - IONOS using Plesk

Tags: php, laravel, api-design, plesk, laravel-9

I've got a VPS with IONOS (was 1&1) and running Plesk Obsidian and I am up to date using Laravel 9. Now I've hit a snag, all I want to do is add a simple subdomain :-

**api.trolleyspotting.fun**

So what would be `https://trolleyspotting.fun/api/v1/trolleys/all`

points to
`https://api.trolleyspotting.fun/v1/trolleys/all`

My issue is when I add the following code to `routes/api.php`

`Route::domain('api.' . env('APP_URL'))->group(function() {`

```
`Route::get('v1/trolleys/all', [ApiController:class, 'index']);`
```

`});`

And then go to `https://api.trolleyspotting.fun/v1/trolleys/all` nothing happens! I added an A record for the subdomain in IONOS Domain control panel and it points to the VPS IP address. When I install the laravel application and try to do as above it just does not work. Where am I going wrong? It's added no problem on the Plesk side as a subdomain. Do I need to add something in `routes/web.php` ? I've tried just adding the A record for the subdomain and adding it to the DNS side on Plesk but not physically adding it as a subdomain with its own directories but that didn't work either. I am reaching the end of my patience because I'm not a novice and I have read up but no solutions on here or in tutorials (YouTube too) have worked.

Any advice or answers very much appreciated in advance.

Thanks!

Comment: please use env and config for your route. ex : `Route::domain(config('app.api_url'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest you a simple and straight forward way to implement it.

1. If you want to use sub-domain(like: api.xyz.com) map it from the subdomain management from hosting provider
2. Point it to the public folder of your current laravel app deployment so it will work simple as api.xyz.com/api/{version}/{route_name}

i think you should follow this steps and you are good to go.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I removed the prefix('api') from the RouteServiceProvider.php file and it is now working oh so well. Thank you very much for the comments you guys I do appreciate your time and advice.